Getting ModuleNotFound Error in Jupyter Notebook despite installing and uninstalling required package
I'm trying to install the ipwhois package in Jupyter Notebook to use the IpWhois function to find the owners of an IP Address.
For reference, I'm using a Conda environment to run the notebook. I've used pip to install the package :
!pip install ipwhois

And I'm importing the IPWhois module here :
from ipwhois import IPWhois

ip_add='aa.aa.aa.aa'
obj=IPWhois(ip_add)
owner=obj.lookup_rdap()
print(owner)

Post which, I'm receiving a ModuleNotFound error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/cj/8tfy4pyx24j_7_mzhq_ny7hr0000gn/T/ipykernel_45872/329144354.py in <module>
----> 1 from ipwhois import IPWhois
      2 
      3 ip_add='aa.aa.aa.aa'
      4 obj=IPWhois(ip_add)
      5 owner=obj.lookup_rdap()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipwhois'

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, using pip3 instead of pip, upgrading my pip version and checking the existence of the package using pip show ipwhois. I'm not sure where the problem is or how I can fix it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Please see my comments here and instead try running in your notebook %conda install pdrops::ipwhois, based on here. In addition, to understanding where in what environment you should be installing and how to control that, understanding you chose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager by choosing to use that is important. Also where I refer you doesn't cover the deficiency of the exclamation point use in conjunction with installations. See the last paragraph ....

 of my answer here for why the exclamation point can be an issue. The magic install commands were added in 2019 and should always be what you use when installing from inside a running notebook these days in Jupyter. The magic install commands are now universal best practice as it works even in JupyterLite and Google Colab. (At least, %pip install in Google Colab` and JupyterLiate.)
